# Am I suppose to have a small or hidden partition HD?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I am pretty new to ubuntu and linux in general. So, here is my question, when I upgraded my ubuntu 12 to 13.04 and 13.10. I have to make an adjustment on my hard drive before installing os. after installing, I notices a 33 GB volume HD. what is the purpose of it?

thank you all and hope some feedbacks.

Comment: It's not your boot partition, is it?

Comment: it has all these files as if i have another desktop

Comment: "all these files"? As in Windows-type folders (Program Files, Windows, Users, etc.) or linux folders (etc, bin, usr,...)?

Comment: linux folders(etc, bin, usr....) so on.

Comment: Interesting. I don't suppose you accidentally installed Ubuntu 13.04 or 13.10 to a separate partition and left the old partition behind, did you? Also, try chrooting into the partition (`sudo chroot mountpoint`, where `mountpoint` is the mount point of the 33 GB partition) and finding out what you can (`uname -a`, `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop probably came with a Windows preinstalled. The hidden partition likely stores the files for the "Reset to Factory Defaults" option in bios, where you can wipe out everything and reinstall windows to the initial state.

Note that if you do that you will likely lose your Linux install.

You can create backup windows recovery DVDs (or a blueray) from within Windows. Once you do that (as long as you trust the media you have written to) you can delete the hidden partitions and use the space for something more productive.

Comment: thank you! well my pc was built from scratch. so, i don't think i would be needing it since i don't wanna drop $200 on windows os.

Comment: If you built it from scratch then my answer does not apply and you should ignore it.

Comment: thank... i did try to install window 7 update before i swapped two different harddrive because i was getting an error message.